I am getting issue in quill text editor when i use image and text together my application crashes in flutter
QuillHtmlEditor(
hintText: '',
controller:
createnewsController
.controller,
isEnabled:
true,
minHeight:
300,
textStyle:
_editorTextStyle,
hintTextStyle:
_hintTextStyle,
hintTextAlign:
TextAlign
.start,
padding: const EdgeInsets
.only(
left: 0,
top: 0),
hintTextPadding:
const EdgeInsets
.only(
left:
20),
backgroundColor:
_backgroundColor,
onFocusChanged:
(hasFocus) =>
debugPrint(
'has focus $hasFocus'),
onTextChanged:
(text) async {
await createnewsController
.controller
.getText();
// quillText = text;
},
onEditorCreated: () =>
debugPrint(
'Editor has been loaded'),
onEditorResized:
(height) =>
debugPrint(
'Editor resized $height'),
onSelectionChanged:
(sel) =>
debugPrint(
'index ${sel
.index}, range ${sel
.length}'),
),
i have added the code please check and let me know any solution

Please provide more informations related to the error, like the console.
